# Drupal: Additional attributes for taxonomy terms

Tags: drupal, cck, drupal-taxonomy

I need to assign dynamic attributes (like entity types) to a custom content type that  created. Those entity types have a name and 2 additional attributes. I've not seen a way to assign additional attributes to a taxonomy term, so I think I shoud use a CCK field and make a reference to it in my main CCK, is it true? I thought that this was a typical use-case for a taxonomy but if I cannot add attributes they are not so useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Node Auto Term](http://drupal.org/project/nat) module (or one of the several alternatives, NAT just looks most developed), which (effectively) turns taxonomy terms into nodes, and vocabs into content types. This means you can add fields to the content type using CCK, and effectively add attributes to your terms.

Note that this module (and the others that perform the same function) just enforces relationships between a vocab and a content type, and terms for that vocab and nodes of that type.

You can actually achieve the same thing without a module if you don't need automation or enforcement - just create one node per term, tagged with that term, and pull that node into views to access the fields.